# I have two versions of a function to count leading hash(#) characters, which is better?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I wrote a piece of code to count the leading hash(#) character of a line, which is much like a heading line in `Markdown`

```
### Line one          -> return 3
######## Line two     -> return 6 (Only care about the first 6 characters.
```

**Version 1**

```
(defn
  count-leading-hash
  [line]
  (let [cnt (count (take-while #(= % \#) line))]
    (if (> cnt 6) 6 cnt)))
```

**Version 2**

```
(defn
  count-leading-hash
  [line]
  (loop [cnt 0]
    (if (and (= (.charAt line cnt) \#) (< cnt 6))
      (recur (inc cnt))
      cnt)))
```

I used `time` to measure both tow implementations, found that the first version based on `take-while` is 2x faster than version 2. Taken `"###### Line one"` as input, version 1 took *0.09 msecs*, version 2 took about *0.19 msecs*.

**Question 1. Is it `recur` that slows down the second implementation?**

**Question 2. Version 1 is closer to functional programming paradigm , is it?**

**Question 3. Which one do you prefer? Why?** (You're welcome to write your own implementation.)

#### --Update--

After reading the [doc of cloujure](http://clojuredocs.org/quickref/Clojure%20Core), I came up with a new version of this function, and I think it's much clear.

```
(defn
  count-leading-hash
  [line]
  (->> line (take 6) (take-while #(= \# %)) count))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: No. `recur` is pretty fast. For every function you call, there is a bit of overhead and "noise" from the VM: the REPL needs to parse and evaluate your call for example, or some garbage collection might happen. That's why benchmarks on such tiny bits of code don't mean anything.

Compare with:

```
(defn
  count-leading-hash
  [line]
  (let [cnt (count (take-while #(= % \#) line))]
    (if (> cnt 6) 6 cnt)))

(defn
  count-leading-hash2
  [line]
  (loop [cnt 0]
    (if (and (= (.charAt line cnt) \#) (< cnt 6))
      (recur (inc cnt))
      cnt)))

(def lines ["### Line one" "######## Line two"])

(time (dorun (repeatedly 10000 #(dorun (map count-leading-hash lines)))))
;; "Elapsed time: 620.628 msecs"
;; => nil
(time (dorun (repeatedly 10000 #(dorun (map count-leading-hash2 lines)))))
;; "Elapsed time: 592.721 msecs"
;; => nil
```

No significant difference.

2: Using `loop`/`recur` is not idiomatic in this instance; it's best to use it only when you really need it and use other available functions when you can. There are many useful functions that operate on collections/sequences; check [ClojureDocs](http://clojuredocs.org/quickref/Clojure%20Core#Collections+-+Sequences) for a reference and examples. In my experience, people with imperative programming skills who are new to functional programming use `loop`/`recur` a lot more than those who have a lot of Clojure experience; `loop`/`recur` can be a code smell.

3: I like the first version better. There are lots of different approaches:

```
;; more expensive, because it iterates n times, where n is the number of #'s
(defn count-leading-hash [line]
  (min 6 (count (take-while #(= \# %) line))))

;; takes only at most 6 characters from line, so less expensive
(defn count-leading-hash [line]
  (count (take-while #(= \# %) (take 6 line))))

;; instead of an anonymous function, you can use `partial`
(defn count-leading-hash [line]
  (count (take-while (partial = \#) (take 6 line))))
```

**edit:**
How to decide when to use `partial` vs an anonymous function?

In terms of performance it doesn't matter, because `(partial = \#)` evaluates to `(fn [& args] (apply = \# args))`. `#(= \# %)` translates to `(fn [arg] (= \# arg))`. Both are very similar, but `partial` gives you a function that accepts an arbitrary number of arguments, so in situations where you need it, that's the way to go. `partial` is the λ (lambda) in [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-expression). I'd say, use what's easier to read, or `partial` if you need a function with an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: "instead of an anonymous function, you can use `partial`", by this you mean `partial` is better than anonymous function, do you? If so, what's the benefit, performance?

Comment: I'm impartial (excuse the pun!) - I've edited my answer to include my thoughts on `partial` vs. anonymous functions

Answer (score 6):

1. IMO it isn't useful to take time measurements for small pieces of code
2. Yes, version 1 is more functional
3. I prefer version 1 because it is easier to spot errors
4. I prefer version 1 because it is less code, thus less cost to maintain.

I would write the function like this:

```
(defn count-leading-hash [line]
  (count (take-while #{\#} (take 6 line))))
```

Comment: I really like the idea of `(take 6 line)`, brilliant!

Answer (score 3):

1. No, it's the reflection used to invoke `.charAt`.  Call `(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)` before creating the function, and you'll see the warning.
2. Insofar as it uses [HOFs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), sure.
3. The first, though `(if (> cnt 6) 6 cnt)` is better written as `(min 6 cnt)`.

Comment: `(min 6 cnt)` is a good improvement to a bad approach, though - using `count` here means it will fail on any infinite sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Micro-benchmarks on the JVM are almost always misleading, unless you really know what you're doing. So, I wouldn't put too much weight on the relative performance of your two solutions.

The first solution is more idiomatic. You only really see explicit loop/recur in Clojure code when it's the only reasonable alternative. In this case, clearly, there is a reasonable alternative.

Another option, if you're comfortable with regular expressions:

```
(defn count-leading-hash [line]
     (count (or (re-find #"^#{1,6}" line) "")))
```